# Is it possible to add some VB class in asp.net[c#] project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using asp.net [C#] in a project. It is a big project including of classes. I need to add some VB class to achieve some calculation. Is it possible to Call a VB class from C# code?

Comment: The only time that I know of when you can mix VB and C# code in the same project is "WEB Site" project. In the case of web site, it is asp_net compiles your classes and `*.*proj` file is not involved, and this is why it is possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not denying the fact mentioned in all other answers that we can’t mix languages in same project. **Best approach will be to create a separate library and use that as a reference in your project.** Which will be easier to implement and better approach in terms of maintainability.

But in case of an **ASP.NET** Website we can definitely use multiple classes from different language. To achieve this we can configure our webapplciation to create subfolders of the **App_Code** folders as separate compliable units and each folder can then contain source code in different programming language.

You can change your configuration file as following.

[image]

Once done add respective classes for the defined languages in the folders. C# in the CSCode folder and VB in the VBCode folder as following.

[image]

Finally you can use it in other area of your website as following.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just add a reference of your `VB` project inside your `C#` project and use the class.

Because both `VB.NET` and `C#` compile into IL (intermediate language), you can simply create a library (a DLL file) in VB.NET, and then use that library in C#.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add VB.net Class library project to your C# solution.
2. Add all the VB.net classes to that class library
3. Add reference to VB.Net class library project from C# project

Answer (score 0):

No - you cannot mix languages in SAME project - to answer the question in your title.

what you could do is reference the VB assembly containing that class.